# Chart with tool tip values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, chart.js

I am really confused how to create charts in angular js. Using angular-chart.js, I am able to create one pie and bar chart. But not able to add tooltip. I am exactly looking something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/5gyfykka/14/) to display percentage as tooltip.

**javascript**

```js
$scope.labels = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"];
$scope.data = [8000, 6000, 22000, 500];
$scope.color = ['#90EE90', '#FF6600', '#8080FF'];
$scope.options = {
  legend: {
    display: true
  },
  responsive: true, // set to false to remove responsiveness. Default responsive value is true.
  tooltipEvents: [],
  showTooltips: true,
  tooltipCaretSize: 0,
  onAnimationComplete: function() {
    this.showTooltip(this.segments, true);
  }
}
```

**html**

```html
<canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-colors="color" chart-options="options">
</canvas>
```

I am able to create chart. But how to set tooltip with only values or convert the values into percentage ? I have tried [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuhp8k5f/154/) which is also not working. I tried using the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/5gyfykka/14/) in angular 1.4 version but it gives error saying value is not defined. Can anyone help me in creating chart with values on tooltip as percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [jtblin/angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) as the libraries in the sample are not showing percentage.

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/p09orpef/)

also added tooltip callback

```
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        //get the concerned dataset
        var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
        //calculate the total of this data set
        var total = dataset.data.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
          return previousValue + currentValue;
        });
        //get the current items value
        var currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
        //calculate the precentage based on the total and current item, also this does a rough rounding to give a whole number
        var precentage = Math.floor(((currentValue / total) * 100) + 0.5);

        return precentage + "%";
      }
    }
  }
```